# How to use Kafka Connect on Windows 7 as I don't see connect-standalone or distributed.bat under /bin/Windows folder in kafka 2.10.0.1?

Tags: installation, apache-kafka, windows-7-x64, apache-kafka-connect

I trying to use Apache Kafka with postgresql, both are running on windows 7 machine. Now, I want to use Kafka-Connect on windows. Is there any possible way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops :)
I'd do the following:

1. File a JIRA to Apache Kafka, so we can track this problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA
2. If you have some batch skills, try to write your own batch file, using the shell scripts and other batch files as examples. It only requires calling the appropriate Java jar and class with the right parameters.
3. If this works, contribute your files to Apache Kafka and join the elites of Apache contributors - it will definitely look nifty on your CV :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@echo off
rem ...

SetLocal
IF ["%KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS%"] EQU [""] (
    set KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:%~dp0../../config/connect-log4j.properties
)

%~dp0kafka-run-class.bat org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone %*
EndLocal
```

Good luck